# Flutter Button inside a Wheel ListView Widget

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, widget, gesturedetector

I am using a `ListWheelScrollView` more specific a `clickable` one.
([clickable_list_wheel_view](https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view))

I am trying to have a `button` inside my `itemWidget` but I can not click it. This is my `list`:

```
return ClickableListWheelScrollView(
  scrollController: _scrollController,
  itemHeight: _itemHeight,
  itemCount: months.length,
  scrollOnTap: true,
  onItemTapCallback: (index) {
    print(index)
  },
  child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemExtent: _itemHeight,
    physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
    diameterRatio: 3,
    squeeze: 0.95,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
      // print(index);
    },
    childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
      builder: (context, index) => MonthCardWidget(
        month: months[index],
      ),
      childCount: months.length,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Inside my `MonthCardWidget` I have this simple `button`:

```
          Container(
            height: 45,
            width: 45,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: IconButton(
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              onPressed: () {
                print('flip');
              },
              icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/flip.svg',
                  height: 20, width: 20),
            ),
          ),
```

Everything is getting displayed just fine but `onPressed` is never called on my `button`. I guess the `GestureDetector` is overriding the button? Is there any workaround for this? I couldn't find anything on this.

The `GestureDetector` is simply on top of the `listView`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_listHeight == .0) {
      return MeasureSize(
        child: Container(
          child: widget.child,
        ),
        onChange: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _listHeight = value.height;
          });
        },
      );
    }

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _onTap,
      onTapUp: (tapUpDetails) {
        _tapUpDetails = tapUpDetails?.localPosition;
      },
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
```

Comment: You mention a GestureDetector in your description but it's not on the code you shared.

Comment: @JoãoSoares I linked `clickableListWheelView`. Basically the whole `list` is wrapped inside a `GestureDetector`.

Comment: But we can't see that because you haven't shared that part of the code. The options that you've set in the GestureDetector, etc. If you want to get help, share the code that may influence your issue.

Comment: @JoãoSoares updated my question, does that help? Like I said, that is from the package that I linked. I didn't change anything there. You can check out the link, maybe that makes things clearer

Answer (score 0):

The click will never reach your GestureDetector, you need to specify the click in the ClickableListWheelScrollView here:

```
  onItemTapCallback: (index) {
print(index)
```

},

If the print you have there isn't printing, then get with the ClickableListWheelScrollView plugin publisher.  You'll need logic to reach the changes you want with the button based on the index number passed from the ClickableListWheelScrollView I think....so a map of setState functions might do it.

Think of the button just being a view, and you're just running the function logic in parallel to each button based on its position in the list.  The button is buried under the list, you need a layer above the ListWheel, which is the Clickable plugin, but obviously it becomes disconnected from the button, so you need to create logic to link them based on the index value, which is the position of the object in the list.

What I typically do:

```
onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
  // print(index);
},
```

1. This Will return the index position of the item in your list.  Use this to change a variable.
2. Wrap your scroller in a GestureDetector.
3. In the Gesture Detector, write or call a function that takes your index position variable and performs your function as you desire.
4. If you need to control where in your list position the scroll begins, or remember its position when you rebuild etc, use a FixedExtentScrollController with an initialItem.

Everything slaves off the index of the onSelectedItemChanged in this way, and you use the FixedExtentScrollController to set a starting position at build.  Remember that the list begins at 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I know this is a tough problem... And I have not found a solution yet. I also opened an issue: https://github.com/Cilestal/clickable_list_wheel_view/issues/1

Comment: I looked at your post, and I'm not following exactly what you're trying to do.  I just made a few of these.  Instead of using the package you used above, I wrapped the Scroller in a gesture detector....I'll edit my answer to explain is a bit more clearly maybe.